# While loop returning AFTER exit (IEnumerable involved) causing bounds error

Tags: c#, loops, search, ienumerable

I know there are many ways to skin this cat, but I'm having some issues with a basic while loop that exits properly, but returns (and increases the counter) upon returning an IEnumerable.ToList() from the parent function. Basically what I'm trying to do is search a list of individual keywords and filter down the result set until I get only items that contain ALL keywords.

It exits the loop, and then as soon as the return is hit, it goes BACK into the loop with the i variable incremented another place (higher than the count variable), so broken[i] throws an outside of bounds error.

While I know there are better ways to execute the search, I'm also very interested in WHY the code is going back into an exited loop, incrementing again, and causing the error - and how to fix it. This is very strange, I've never seen this before. Is it because the .ToList is forcing an enumeration back up the chain?

Code:

```
public IEnumerable<Item> GetItemsForSearch(string search=null)
    {
        ParserDataContext data = new ParserDataContext();            
        if (search != null && search != "")
        {                   
            string[] broken = search.Split(' ');                
            IEnumerable<Item> watches = data.Items.Where(x => x.Title.ToLower().Contains(broken[0].ToLower())).OrderByDescending(x => x.DateListed).ThenByDescending(x => x.ID);

            int i = 1;
            int count = broken.Count();
            while (i < count)
            {
                if (broken[i] != null)
                item = items.Where(x => x.Title.ToLower().Contains(broken[i].ToLower()));
                i++;
            }

            return items.Take(50).ToList();
        }
```

}

Comment: Are you doing anything with threads?

Comment: You are not providing a complete code, it's not clear where is this method called and where it goes after `return`. Consider to provide [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why use a while loop here when based on the code you've provided, a for-loop would be preferred for readability?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> While I know there are better ways to execute the search, I'm also very interested in WHY the code is going back into an exited loop, incrementing again, and causing the error

The first thing is to understand what is actually going on: the code does not go back into a loop that has exited, it merely uses the value of the variable `i` at a wrong point in time, i.e. after it has been incremented. This is a known feature: the compiler captures `i` of `broken[i]` directly, without making its copy.

Apparently, this feature has been annoying enough for Microsoft to announce a fix for a common case of this error in C# 5.0 (specifically, closing over the loop variable in `foreach` loop).

> and how to fix it.

For users of C# 4.5, a simple fix is to declare a temporary variable instead of using `i`. The compiler will capture the value of the temporary, making the behavior as you expect:

```
while (i < count) {
    if (broken[i] != null) {
        var tmp = broken[i].ToLower();
           items = items.Where(x => x.Title.ToLower().Contains(tmp));
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

A better approach would be collecting all the broken words together, and then running a selection in a single shot, like this:

```
var allBroken = broken.Where(b => b != null).Select(ToLower).ToList();
var items = items
    .Select(item => new {Item = item, Title = item.Title.ToLower()})
    .Where(pair => allBroken.Any(broken => pair.Title.Contains(broken)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: The fix is only for the `foreach` construct (from the link below: *UPDATE: We are taking the breaking change. In C# 5, the loop variable of a foreach will be logically inside the loop, and therefore closures will close over a fresh copy of the variable each time. The "for" loop will not be changed.*)

Comment: [Eric Lipper's Blog - Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).

Comment: Wow this worked like a champ. I can't upvote because I don't have enough reputation. Can someone help me out there? Thanks!